# How to use console.log() after the console object's functions have been overwritten?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

I need console.log(), but it is not working because someone has done something to block it in a production site. Is there any other way to print to the console? Or to use an alert that would print a full object like console.log() does? Or a way to redefine console.log() so that it works again?

The jQuery library is available to me.

Comment: Don't know much about console, but I think console is a native interface so it may depends on how they block it. For alert, in most cases, if you don't have any circular pointer in the object, you may try: alert(JSON.stringify(object)) .

Comment: One workaround could be is to get a reference to the console and its methods before any other script is executed... like in the page header add a script which will get the reference like `var _console = console,
    _log = _console.log;` then `_log.call(_console, 'some message')`

Answer (score 7):

Depending how they blocked it, you could use something like this.

```
    console.log = function fake() {};
    console.log("oh no! it's not working!")

    delete console.log;
    console.log("whew.  back again.");
```

This simply removes the custom definition that was applied.

If they have done something more clever than that, you might be able to do something like this.  This creates a brand new `iframe` with a completely new `window` object, from which you can extract a pristine `console`.  This only works if the body element already exists.

```
    var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(frame);

    var myConsoleLog = function(message) {
        (frame.contentWindow || frame).console.log(message);
    }
    myConsoleLog("this works too!");
```

Answer (score 2):

---

You could stringify the object and append it on the page. JSON.stringify has two additional params, replacer (ignore), and number of spaces, aka it will do some of the formatting for you.

As simple as this:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)));
```

Slightly more complex example:
http://codepen.io/JAStanton/pen/qehpH

I could be more helpful if you tell me what you hope to get out of it. Do you just care about object / properties? Do you want to know the functions on the object etc...?

Comment: I was using jQuery `.find()`, expecting to get a certain DOM node. But when I inserted it into the page, nothing happened. So I wanted to see what I was getting back from `.find()`